# How to fix layout orientation to vertical?

Tags: android, android-orientation

How to fix layout orientation to portrait and do not allow changing from portrait to landscape during run time?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

In your `AndroidMainfest.xml` file find the tags of the activities you wish to lock to a given rotation, and add this attribute:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Can you describe how it doesn't work?

Comment: @parvus for me, when i added this attribute `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in manifest according the answer i still can make rotation... eventually i found solution in next , i have added this line `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` on `onCreate();` of each activity

Comment: Hi Could you take a look at my issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/74940364/10110990

Answer (score 24):

Use `setRequestedOrientation()` as shown:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Personally I prefer this, If you want to change the Orientation this is really handy, otherwise use XML if your only ever going to place the device in that orientation.

Answer (score 16):

in your activity parameters in Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.statepermit" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/stateheader" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".statepermit" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

**android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to freeze orientation at runtime, then you you can implement this:

[Android: Temporarily disable orientation changes in an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity/3611554#3611554)

I use a similar approach and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fix the orientation of one Activity in your project, you have to open the `Manifest.xml` and put in the section of parameters of the desired Activity (before the closure of the first tag  `< activity…>` ):

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` if you want VERTICAL fixed orientation

`android:screenOrientation="landscape"` if you want HORIZONTAL fixed orientation

Comment: Hi can you, help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940364/android-13-landscape-orientation-are-not-actually-landscape

Answer (score 2):

In your `AndroidMainfest.xml` just write this in your activity you declare,

If you want in layout vertical than use

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

If you want in layout landscape than use

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```