# android:orientation="horizontal" does not function

Tags: android-orientation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

When I start this activity, its orientation just inherits the current orientation, no change is made, did I miss something anywhere?

Comment: post your entire xml file

Comment: are u trying to fix screen orientation to landscape and portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "work" because by default LinearLayout has an horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 0):

The orientation in your xml is the orientation of the LinearLayout. That means that any views you put into the linear layout will be added beside each other horizontally. See docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation

It sounds like you are wanting to fix the screen orientation - try this question for example: [How to fix layout orientation to vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702086/fix-layout-orientation-to-vertical)