# Android 13 - Landscape orientation are not actually landscape

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation, android-12, android-13

In android-13 devices, am facing issue with playing video within the exoplayer. when user rotates them devices video player will be set to full screen. but in this case rotating device can changes orientation but showing app in portrait mode only (whole page)

Expected: rotating device should fill the screen as like Android 12 and previous versions

Tried

```
android:name=".ui.fullscreenVideo.VideoPlayerActivity"
android:exported="true"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="userLandscape"
```

but issue not fixed (

[image]

When user rotate them mobile, video activity also want to get rotated like previous android 12 and below versions

The problem is Android-13, showing portrait screen mode in landscape orientation

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing same issue in android 13 android:screenOrientation="locked"

I changed the setting to default/nosensor to resolve the issue currently.

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="false"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|locale|keyboardHidden|uiModel"
android:screenOrientation="locked"
```