# setRequestedOrientation for landscape loads portrait Layout

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am developing an app that needs to run strictly in portrait mode  in smart phones and strictly in landscape mode in tablets. I am using the following code to set the orientation manually in onCreate method of my login activity:

```
 if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        }
```

Where the bool value comes false in Tablets. However the orientation is changed to landscape; still the layout file is picked from  "layout_large" folder instead of "layout_large_land" folder. Hence my view looks stretched.

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962172/setrequestedorientation-before-showing-progressdialog-leads-to-crash).

But it doesn't help.!

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Make sure you're NOT setting `android:configChanges="orientation"` for your activity in AndroidManifest.

I'm guessing the problem with that is that `setRequestedOrientation` potentially triggers an orientation config change, HOWEVER by using `android:configChanges="orientation"` this config change is not registered by the system.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the Manifest setting, you would have to implement your own recreation mechanic for this particular configuration change.

It may look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only))
        recreate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a folder like this for Tab & mobile

[image]

`layout` folder is for mobile and `layout-sw720dp` for Tabs. 720 dp is width which tells 720+ dp will use that folder for layout.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: can you tell me what is the `setContentView()` and what is the layout file name in your layout folder? For both mobile and tab

Answer (score 0):

Being late in this thread but will help in the future SO. In my case I was programmatically changing the orientation of the screen by calling

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

OR

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

depending on the user's action. I have also created a separate layout for portrait and landscape but every time on changing the screen from portrait to landscape, it always loading the portrait screen in landscape.

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, I've set this

```
 android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

So, To solve this problem, Need to remove the orientation from `android:configChanges` then it works. This is what android documentation [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) mentioned

> The "orientation" value prevents restarts when the screen orientation
> changes.