# Fragment dynamic UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am a newbie in android app. May I make fragment orientation change (dynamic UI) no use  tag in xml file(layout)?

I found a lot of example where use  tag in xml file(layout)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is about but maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity

Comment: yes you can rotate stuff programmatically aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)
here handle new Configuration, and if it is changed do you logic