# IntentService operations with a ProgressDialog?

Tags: java, android

I have been acheiving a network operation , initiated by an activity through IntentService .

However during the download operation I want to block the UI by means of a ProgressDialog .

The problem is that that ProgressBar has a handle to an activity , it is strongly coupled with it and this would cause problems if the screen's orientation is changed during the operation .

If Activity A , starts IntentService B , I can introduce a ProgressDialog right after . But if before my reciever is invoked (before the network operation is completed) , the orientation changes ; I will end up with an orphaned reference to the ProgressDialog hence wont be able to dismiss it .

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think you really mean "block the UI"; I think you mean "put up an indefinite activity indicator and ignore input until something finishes".
2. If so, use a ProgressBar widget in your UI. Start with the widget's android:visibility="GONE". When you start the background work, set android:visibility="VISIBLE" and disable the UI controls you want to block. When the background work is done, reverse everything.
3. To get back to the Activity once the background work is done, implement *two* options: notification with content Intent going to your Activity, and broadcast Intent with receiver for your Activity. If your Activity is in the background, the notification appears and by clicking it the user goes back to your Activity. If your Activity is in the foreground, get the broadcast Intent in onReceive(). Either way, alert the user that the background work is done (and dismiss the notification).
4. Use onPause() and onResume() to maintain the UI state, by saving or restoring visibility and enabled/disabled settings.

Doing it this way, it doesn't matter what happens to your Activity while the IntentService is running.

You should also look at the Android training class [Transferring Data Without Draining the Battery](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html). It will help you do efficient, user-friendly network operations. There are a lot of other tips out there about using the network correctly on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is temporarily disable and then re-enable the orientation change of your Activity while the progress bar is present.  This can be done by means of setting the appropriate flags.

I couldn't recall the specifics but found a quick link with the following information:

[Temporarily enable/disable orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity)