# Orientation screen landscape

Tags: android

I'm making a app and it works with the virtual device but when I run this app in an android device just run as a Landscape, does any have any idea why?

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // Our only layout for this app is main.xml
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

an my manifest xml

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.colors.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
```

Comment: Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity

Answer (score 1):

Add this in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

to fix it permanent

remove

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);`
and 
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: doesnt wokk this... still the same

Comment: remove the landscape sensor

Comment: Now I can't rotate to landscape