# Android: Prevent Orientation to change programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, android-studio, android-orientation

I'm using:

```
setRequestedOrientation(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
```

and later on:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

it prevents the orientation to change until a task is finished, but it only works on portrait, when app is on landscape it doesn't stop orientation to change.

Any suggestions?
Oim~

Comment: if you want to keep the orientation fixed to potrait mode then use android:orientation=potrait in each activity in the manifest

Comment: This can help you to disable rotating device programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614089/3864698

Comment: @therealprashant I'm not trying to fix the orientation for the entire application run but only while a crucial task is running.

Comment: @QArea that didn't work either but it led me to find the actual answer: getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() lets you know in wich of all 4 orientation the devise is in, and then you can just fix it using the setRequestedOrientation()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work properly in all cases now.

To fix the screen:

```
if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()== Surface.ROTATION_0)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()== Surface.ROTATION_90)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()== Surface.ROTATION_270)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
```

and then to allow rotations again:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Oim~

Comment: Do you test it on tablets? Tablets have different orientation. Rotation_0 means Landscape.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I've tested the application on a tablet only once, and as far as I remember it was fine, but I wasn't actively trying to test this. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file with your activity try this

```
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Inside application tag in manifest file try this

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Exact same behaviour, it works fine while in portrait, but does nothing while on landscape.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but keeps being the exact same, it works properly while on portrait, and nothing while on landscape. I kept the previous lines and added the second ones.