# Android - Window leak error on ProgressDialog when device is in landscape

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-orientation

I have looked at many questions here and searched on Internet but couldn't find any specific solution. The main problem other questions refer to is, `Window Leak Error` when go from Portrait to Landscape or vice versa. And answer is mainly, because `Activity` is destroyed and recreated, hence `Window Leak Error`.

But my problem is, my device is already in Landscape, and app was working fine, previous Activities were smoothly running, but when I try to display `ProgressDialog`, `Window Leak Error` is thrown. Exact same code works fine when in Portrait orientation.

```
class DownloadYearChartAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
    private String username;
    private String city;

    private Resources resources;
    private Location locationOfCity = null;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public DownloadYearChartAsyncTask(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        resources = getResources();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CityActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.title_progress_dialog);
        progressDialog.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.first_message_progress_dialog));
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        boolean userUpdated = false;

        if(locationOfCity != null && city != null && !city.isEmpty()) {
            try
            {
                UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(CityActivity.this);
                User user = userDAO.readUser();

                if(user == null) {
                    if(username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
                        user = new User(0, username, city, locationOfCity.getLatitude(), locationOfCity.getLongitude());
                        userUpdated = userDAO.createUser(user);
                    }
                }

                    if(username == null) {
                        user.setLocation(city);
                        user.setLatitude(locationOfCity.getLatitude());
                        user.setLongitude(locationOfCity.getLongitude());

                        userUpdated = userDAO.updateUser(user);
                    }
                }
                userDAO.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

        if(userUpdated)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CityActivity.this, TodayActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean allDaysEntered = false;

        try {
            city = params[0];
            locationOfCity = MyJsonUtil.getLocationOfCity(params);

            List<Day> yearChart = MyJsonUtil.getYearChart(locationOfCity.getLatitude(), locationOfCity.getLongitude());


            if(yearChart != null && !yearChart.isEmpty()) {
                YearChartDAO yearChartDAO = new YearChartDAO(CityActivity.this);
                allDaysEntered = yearChartDAO.createYearChartWithDays(yearChart);
                yearChartDAO.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return allDaysEntered;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: please show your code..

Comment: the progressdialog code or the whole AsyncTask ??

Comment: I think I have found the problem, but solution is still weird, check comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614089/1708390)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my code, where I used `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);`

Because, according to [Kevin Gaudin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343816/kevin-gaudin)'s comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3614089/1708390).

> It looks like if you call
>   `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);`
>   when the device is not in its default orientation usage, then the
>   activity orientation is immediately changed (destroyed and recreated)
>   to the device default orientation. For example, on a phone, if you
>   hold it in landscape orientation, then the activity is switched to
>   portrait and back to landscape when reactivating sensors. The same
>   opposite issue with an Archos A5 IT : using it in portrait causes the
>   activity to be switched to landscape and back to portrait.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821998/1708390) is the solution that I found, answered by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware). But this solution is a little lengthy.

So for people who are in a rush, this is the technique that I used but this solution is not perfect.

1 - In `Manifest`, add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your activity in which you want to show the `ProgressDialog`.

2 - In that `Activity`, just override `OnConfigurationChange(Configuration newConfig)`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```