# Permission Dialog while Screen Orientation change in Android Marshmallow crashing the App

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

How to handle permission dialog box during screen orientation in Android M devices?

In my case, after changing screen orientation, and clicking Okay button in permission dialog box crashes the app.

Comment: removed greetings/salutations as per the SO ask questions rule

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My workaround for this situation:**
Once permission dialog box is coming, I am locking up the screen to its current orientation (portrait/landscape). When user presses the button, I am unlocking the screen.

For Locking/unlocking the orientation, refer the link: 
[Android: Temporarily disable orientation changes in an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity/32885911#32885911)