# Disable upside down (180 degree) rotation in Android

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

My Android device can rotate in all orientations (0, 90, 180, 270). How do I disable upside down (180 degree) only? Is that possible?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity) answer, This might have help you.

Comment: @androidOnHigh thanks you so much but this is different issue

Comment: @android_Muncher I learned forums but didn't find solution in this case

Answer (score 0):

> You just have to define the property below inside the activity element in your AndroidManifest.xml file. It will restrict your orientation to portrait.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.demo_spinner.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```