# Minimum android tablet size information needed

Tags: android

I want to develop application with **single binary for Android device and for Android tablets with target android 2.1 version.**

My orientation also depends upon whether app is running on device or on tablet.

So i just want to know, is there any specification like tablet should be **minimum of "X" inches.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is heaps of information on screen sizes and each device can be different so you should use the [Android standards talked about here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to figure out exactly what screen you are dealing with and react accordingly. There are no hard and fast "atleast X inches" rules; just different screen sizes of different resolutions. You can use the Android manifest to restrict the screen sizes to just the ones that you want to support.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i support my application for all screen sizes: small, normal, large & xlarge and according drawables are places under respective folders. I want to support portrait mode for mobile devices and portrait/landscape orientation for tablets

Comment: @Zoombie: "I want to support portrait mode for mobile devices and portrait/landscape orientation for tablets" Thats nice. It sounds like you have the right information to do that. What is the problem? Maybe you want to set the orientation at runtime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366706/how-to-lock-orientation-during-runtime

Comment: Yes i have set orientation at runtime, implemented a singleton pattern for application, which checks device's current screen size in inches, and if inches are more than 7, then i consider it as tablet and so set orientation according. I just doubt about this, as i feel its not best way to do.

Answer (score 2):

> My orientation also depends upon whether app is running on device or on tablet.

Your application should depend on whether the screen is `small`, `normal`, `large`, or `xlarge`. There is no concept of "device or on tablet" in Android.

> is there any specification like tablet should be minimum of "X" inches.

There is no concept of "tablet" in Android. What a user will think of as a "tablet" will tend to be `large` or `xlarge` screen size.

Comment: Hi commonsware, thanks for your invaluable information, i support my application for all screen sizes: small, normal, large & xlarge and according drawables are places under respective folders. I want to support portrait mode for mobile devices and portrait/landscape orientation for tablets