# how to make android apps only work on screen flipped one way?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I'm making an android app but it works best if the phone/tablet is flipped horizontal.. how do I make the screen lock at that and make it to where it doesn't flip going vertical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) in the `<activity>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search through past Stack Overflow questions turns up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366706/how-to-lock-orientation-during-runtime):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I tried looking but I didn't know how to word it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to only define a activity layout for the landscape orientation.  res/layouts-landscape.