# Programmatically disabling screen rotations in the entire Android application

Tags: android, orientation

How do I programmatically disable screen rotations for an entire Android application?

Comment: are you ok to do it in every activity? May be this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android

Comment: check the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366706/how-to-lock-orientation-during-runtime

Comment: No, i have more activity in  my application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in keep it in portrait or Landscape no matter which way device is tilted?
You need to add this to your manifest inside the activity that you want to limit

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait" //Or landscape for horizontal.
```

If you want it different between activities just make your manifest look like this.

```
        <activity android:name=".Activity1" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">       
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity2" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity3" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
```

Comment: i want portrait orientation for the entire application

Comment: Just have to make all the activities look like .Activity2. Enjoy!

Comment: `programmatically`!

Answer (score 3):

Fix the orientation in android manifest for every activity

```
        <activity  android:name=".SomeNewDesignActivity"  
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"  ></activity>
```

Comment: fix every ativity orientation as you want portrait/landscape etc

Comment: no every activity has its own orientation.So you have to set this attribute for every activity in application manifest

Answer (score 2):

Too late to the party!

Anyway if you want to disable rotation without forcing the user to choose landscape or portrait you can use in each activity in the manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="locked"
```

So your manifest should look like this

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity1" 
      android:screenOrientation="locked">       
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity2" 
      android:screenOrientation="locked">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity3" 
      android:screenOrientation="locked">
    </activity>
```

So the app will keep the current orientation the user decided to use.

The same behaviour can be obtained programamtically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do screen orientation to potrait/landscap for entire app -

```
Add following lines in your app theme - 

for making all activity portrait - 



<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
</style>
```

for making all activity landscape -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">landscape</item>
</style>
```