# How do you make a tablet so the screen won't flip?

Tags: android, landscape

How can I make the tablet to always stay in landscape orientation and never go into portrait orientation, even if the user of my app tilts it sideways?

Comment: You need to [search better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271886/programatically-disabling-screen-rotations-in-entire-application-android) before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest under application add android:screenOrientation="landscape"