# How can we lock the camera screen orientation during the camera capture process?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-4.2-jelly-bean, cameracapturetask

Our camera takepicture takes around 10-15 seconds (due to custom camera hardware).
What I need is during this process of 10-15 seconds, I would not want the user to change the screen orientation.

I have placed the takepicture call in doInBackground of Async task.

In the onPreExecute() method I have placed

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);`

And in onPostExecute I placed

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

This solution doesn't work for me and causes the camera and device to be crashed and I had to reboot the device.

Comment: This link seems relevant:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366706/how-to-lock-orientation-during-runtime

Comment: @AnxGotta The above solution doesnt work for me in Tablets but works great in Phones.

Comment: IF it crashes.. posting the stacktrace would help explain the issue. It will likely be a problem with something you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try blocking the orientation from the AndroidManifest ? by adding the below line in your camera activity

```
<activity android:label="@string/activity_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

or

```
<activity android:label="@string/activity_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```