# Disable app rotation if resolution is small

Tags: android, kotlin, responsive-design, android-jetpack-compose, screen-rotation

I am currently working on an Android App written in Kotlin with Jetpack Compose. My goal is to get a responsive app that runs on smartphones and tables responsively. To do this I get the user's curent width and then decide on that width how I will display the UI because in some cases I have to show something else.

I get the current width of the user's display by using a BoxWithConstraints:

```
BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
{
   val largeScreen = this.maxWidth > 1000.dp
}
```

This works fine for now but when a user is rotating the screen on his smartphone to landscape I get problems because of the miniscule height of the device. In my app it does not even make sense to use it in landscape. And I do not want users to use landscape in the app on smartphones. It is fine on tablet devices but not on smartphones.

All I could find was to lock portrait mode for the whole app. But what I would love to have would be to enable landscape and portrait on tablet and enable portrait mode solely on smartphone.

Has anyone also had this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366706/how-to-lock-orientation-during-runtime

Answer (score 1):

There's `getRequestedOrientation()` and a setter for the same. You could use the `largeScreen` boolean to put conditions on the former, and allow landscape rotation if the screen is large, blocking otherwise with the help of the latter.