# Adding scrollview to relative layout messing up everything

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner in android development. My problem is that whenever i am applying scroll view to my `Relativelayout` everything is messing up. Can anyone please tell me how to apply scroll view to my app and one more problem when i am opening my app in portrait mode and when we will change it to landscape mode it will show application has stopped unexpectedly force close i guess it is may be due to because i haven't used scroll view in my application yet but still if anyone has any solution for it please tell me . Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ccc"
    android:padding="30dp" >`enter code here`

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hundred"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tenshotrockets_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ultimate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ultimaterockate_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/power"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/powerrocket_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/twoshots_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/hundred"
                android:text="hundred shots"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/two"
                android:text="two shots"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="ten shots"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/power"
                android:layout_below="@+id/power"
                android:text="power rocket"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="ultimate rocket"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ten"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/music_blast"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/music_blast"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
                android:background="@drawable/threeshots_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ultimate"
                android:text="musical blast"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/music_blast"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:background="@drawable/musical_blast"
                android:text="      " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/music_rocket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Bottle_rock"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Bottle_rock"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                android:background="@drawable/musicalrocket_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/music_rocket"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="musical"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Bottle_rock"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="bottle rocket"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/music_bank"
                android:text="sound"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Bottle_rock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:background="@drawable/musicalsimple_back"
                android:text="      " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/music_bank"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Bottle_rock"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Bottle_rock"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
                android:background="@drawable/musicalsmall"
                android:text="      " />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the **fillViewport** XML attribute in your ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="30dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" > <!-- add this attribute -->

        <RelativeLayout ...

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As for the app crashing when the orientation changes, take note that by default, the application restarts the activity (calls **onCreate** again) whenever there is an orientation change.

I'm guessing that probably messes up your program flow, but since you didn't post code, we can't really comment on it.

Perhaps you want to take a look at the multiple tutorials available.

- [Android orientation change calls onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097909/android-orientation-change-calls-oncreate)
- [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Comment: sir how can i prevent my app from crashing ?

Comment: sir i have implemented this in my scrollview but when i am accessing app in mobile there is no scroll view in it....