# On screen orientation loads again data with Async Task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I make Android application with master/detail pattern. So I have

- ListActivity class which is FragmentActivity and
- ListFragment class which is Fragment

It all works perfect, but when I change screen orientation it calls again AsyncTask and reload all data.

Here is the code for **ListActivity** class where I handle all logic:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Dnevni horoskop");


    if(findViewById(R.id.details_container) != null){
        //Tablet
        mTwoPane = true;

        //Fragment stuff
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        DetailsFragment df = new DetailsFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.details_container, df);
        ft.commit();
    }

    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_list);
    tvNoConnection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_no_internet);
    ivNoConnection = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_no_connection);
    list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_list);

    if(mTwoPane == true){
        list.setNumColumns(1);
        //list.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
    }

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter();      

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            pos = position;
            if(mTwoPane == false){
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("zodiac", zodiacFeed);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
            }
            else if(mTwoPane == true){
                DetailsFragment fragment = (DetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details_container);
                fragment.setHoroscopeText(zodiacFeed.getItem(position).getText());
                fragment.setLargeImage(zodiacFeed.getItem(position).getLargeImage());
                fragment.setSign("Dnevni horoskop - "+zodiacFeed.getItem(position).getName());
                fragment.setSignDuration(zodiacFeed.getItem(position).getDuration());
                 // inflate menu from xml
                /*if(menu != null){
                 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
            }

        }
    });

    if(!Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvNoConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivNoConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

   //Calling AsyncTask to load data
        Log.d("TAG", "loading");
        HoroscopeAsyncTask task = new HoroscopeAsyncTask(pb);
        task.execute();



}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter() {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Set the total list item count
        return names.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate the item layout and set the views
        View listItem = convertView;
        int pos = position;     

        zodiacItem = zodiacList.get(pos);

        if (listItem == null && mTwoPane == false) {
            listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        else if(mTwoPane  == true){
            listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tablet_list_item, null);

        }

        // Initialize the views in the layout
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.iv_horoscope);
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_zodiac_name);
        TextView tvDuration = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);


        iv.setImageResource(zodiacItem.getImage());
        tvName.setText(zodiacItem.getName());
        tvDuration.setText(zodiacItem.getDuration());   

        Animation animation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.push_up);

        listItem.startAnimation(animation);
        animation = null;
        return listItem;
    }

}

  private void getHoroscope() {     

    String urlString = "http://balkanandroid.com/download/horoskop/examples/dnevnihoroskop.php";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE", response_str);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {                       

                        Log.d("TAG", "Response from server : n "
                                + response_str);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("TAG", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

private class HoroscopeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    public HoroscopeAsyncTask(ProgressBar pb1){
        pb = pb1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        getHoroscope();

        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "test u try");

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response_str);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("horoscope");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                Log.d("TAG", "test u for");

                JSONObject horoscopeObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String horoscopeSign = horoscopeObj.getString("name_sign");
                String horoscopeText = horoscopeObj.getString("txt_hrs");

                zodiacItem = new ZodiacItem(horoscopeSign, horoscopeText, duration[i], images[i], largeImages[i]);
                zodiacList.add(zodiacItem);
                zodiacFeed.addItem(zodiacItem);

                //Treba u POJO klasu ubaciti sve.
                Log.d("TAG", "ZNAK: "+zodiacItem.getName()+" HOROSKOP: "+zodiacItem.getText());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);

        }       

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


}
```

Here is the code for **ListFragment** class:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false); 

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe part of the problem could be that the orientation change calls onCreate again.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097909/android-orientation-change-calls-oncreate), and check the second answer.

Just adding configChanges to android manifest won't solve the problem, but if you override onConfigurationChanged, you could for example, set a SharedPreferences value were you say "AsynTaskStarted=true" or something like that, so when the orientation changes, you can check this flag and either start the AsyncTask if not present, r just skip that if it's already running.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android), referenced by the first answer to the first question linked, seems to have more info.

Comment: I know that problem is that the orientation change calls onCreate again, but I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: If you override the onConfigurationChanged, and set a flag there to signal your app that the AsyncTask has started...then you can solve your problem. Read the full answer. Other than that there's no real option, i.e. you can't stoip it from calling onCreate when it rotates, so use a workaround.

Comment: That flag to signal should be store to class witch extends Application?

Comment: What I mean is that you can create a flag of your own. Nothing fancy, just a boolean that you save with SharedPreferences, and that you check before launching AsyncTask. Nothing to do with any specific class.

Answer (score 0):

when orientation changes you can use the following to retain the task:

```
@Override
public HoroscopeAsyncTask onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return task;
}
```

then in your onCreate() you can do something like this:

```
task = (HoroscopeAsyncTask)this.getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
if(task != null) {
    //pass the new progressbar reference to the asynctask
    //implement a method in the asynctask that returns the task result 
    //e.g. result = task.getResult();
    // if the result is not null, it means the task finished its work while orientation
    // changed, if the result is null, onPostExecute will take care of that.
    //if(result != null) { //set the result in the listview }
} else {
    HoroscopeAsyncTask task = new HoroscopeAsyncTask(pb);
    task.execute();
}
```

the code is trying to get the retained taks, if there isn't one (app started) execute a new asynctask, if there is one (orientation change) use the existing running asynctask.

Comment: It still doesn't work, it loads data again. What do you mean by       //attach to your already existing asynctask
?

Comment: Still happens. Maybe is solution to move all logic code from activity to fragment?

Answer (score -1):

try this code in manifest m8 `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: strange. I use fragments and asynchTask in my class, and also the code i posted and i dont get any reloads

Comment: I try to help and i get a minus. Seriously?

Comment: I didn't give you a minus, somebody else did.

Comment: ye i didnt say its you. In general