# android prevent refresh on change orientation

Tags: android, layout, android-orientation

I have `layout/activity_main.xml` and `layout-land/activity_main.xml`. When I change orientation the activity reload again.

I try to use this code `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` and it work the activity is not reloading just what i like but the problem is the layout is not switching from `layout/activity_main.xml` to `layout-land/activity_main.xml`.

How do i switch from `layout/activity_main.xml` to `layout-land/activity_main.xml`. without refreshing the activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android orientation change calls onCreate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097909/android-orientation-change-calls-oncreate)

Comment: Ya i see that but my question has a different. Just what i said `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` is working but the layout is not change from `layout/activity_main.xml` to `layout-land/activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By declaring `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` you instruct Activity Manager to not restart your activity and let you handle configuration change via `onConfigurationChanged()`.

> If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Which means that `onCreate()` will be skipped on configuration changed, and you cannot swap your layout (since `onCreate()` is where you recreate the view).

In your case, you want to change layout, so there is no choice but to refresh your activity, which means to remove `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`. If you want to keep the state, you can save and check the `Bundle` passed to your `onCreate()` to restore state accordingly.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // set your layoutId according to landscape/portrait
    setContentView(layoutId);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // restore your state here
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // save your state here
}
```

For more reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Thank for explanation i understand now my case. I can't use this code ` android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` because its prevent to create new layout for my new orientation  but  How do i save my state? sorry i dont get that part "saving the state" I'm new in android dev.

Comment: Check out this training doc: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Genius! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in your Android Manifest in your <*activity*> tag to restrict the reloading of the activity.

Comment: As you can see i mention that in my question and its work but my problem is if i use that code the layout is not switching from `layout/activity_main.xml` to `layout-land/activity_main.xml`.