# Disable screen rotating on Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

When I press a button, I would like to disable screen rotation ***on all my activities***. How can I do that?

BTW, the phone can be located in landscape or portrait position when the user click the button.

Comment: If you are using compose just open your manifest and add the lines under the activity tag- 

    
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|fontScale"

the second line is to survive the configuration changes like screen size, font scale. Basically it means that when you have your activity open and when you change the font size or font scale of the phone the activity will not change it immedietely and is going to take that change in next screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution:

in manifest.xml:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="MyApplication">
```

in MyApplication.java:

```
public class UPackingListApplication extends Application {

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        newConfig.orientation = [orientation we wanna to use (according to ActivityInfo class)];
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

Comment: I've tried this at the Activity level and it works in terms of setting the internal orientation tracking to whatever you set it to, but in terms of actually stopping the orientation change or being able to physically set the orientation, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 12):

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: If I'd add this line, would it work for all application? or it would work on for the activity?

Comment: It seems like it works only for the activity, where I invoke this code and only until I move to another activity (When I returns to this activity, defalut settings are applied).. I think it is no good practice to invoke such code (checking, should we rotate and rotate screen if we need) for all activities in onResume/onSatrt methods

Answer (score 4):

You can change your AndroidManifest.xml to

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Which informs the OS that you will handle these config changes (by doing nothing.)

See [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Comment: I tied the following:
1) in manifest:
<activity android:name="AboutActivity"     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
2) in AboutActivity:
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   newConfig.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
But anyway activity's screen rotates when device   rotates. 
What did I wrong?

Comment: You call super.onConfigurationChanges() for orientation changes too, which rotates the screen. Use an if structure to determine if the orientation/keyboard state has changed; you should call super only for other changes.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not you call super.  The configuration change has already happened at the time of this callback; it is just being called to tell you about it.

Comment: I seem to recall that the framework throws an exception if you don't call `super` (even if, for this method, it has no particular effect).