# How do you prevent the android screen from being turned sideways?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Whenever I turn the device sideways, everything in my app also turns and becomes distorted. How do I lock it into vertical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` set the orientation on your Activity to `portrait` like this.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: @WRU4Android: Make sure to read CommonsWare's answer too! In fact his answer is the most correct one.

Answer (score 5):

> Whenever I turn the device sideways, everything in my app also turns and becomes distorted. How do I lock it into vertical?

Generally, you do not want to do that.

First, some users have devices with physical keyboards that only operate in landscape mode. Perhaps, for your app, that does not matter. However, any app that uses text input should support landscape mode for these users.

Second, few TVs will operate in portrait mode. It is reasonably likely that your app will look bad on Google TV when it starts supporting Android applications.

Third, even for users whose devices are not forcing them to use landscape, simply prefer to use landscape, for whatever reason.

All of these user bases will think less of applications that force portrait mode, and their opinions may be reflected in ratings on the Android Market.

Most applications should support portrait and landscape, through careful design of the existing layouts and by using `res/layout-land/` to provide replacement layouts where a significant change is required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need this for a game that will only run in portrait. It would not work at all in landscape, and I also have no intention of having it work on Google TV. Also, my game has no need for text input, except in the high scores section, where turning of the screen will be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

For the activity you have defined in the manifest, you need to set the `android:screenOrientation`.

Set it to `portrait` or `landscape`. Make sure it is **not** `sensor`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these SOqs:

- [Disable screen rotating on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329135/android-disable-screen-rotating)
- [Prevent screen rotation on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730855/prevent-screen-rotation-android)