# How to disable screen rotation in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I'm trying to make it so the screen can't rotate when you turn it because it screws up some of the graphics. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can find answers in this questions.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730855/prevent-screen-rotation-android

Comment: check this link if it helps you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329135/android-disable-screen-rotating

Answer (score 2):

Just Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your `<activity>` tag in the manifest to disable orientation.

You can also try to stop the activity from recreating itself when rotating by adding this
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` to your `<activity>` tag.