# How to stop activity recreation in action bar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

As i'm using sherlock library to extend sherlock fragment activity for app, i want to stop activity recreation when screen orientation changes.

Comment: Is this just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568558/how-to-avoid-restarting-activity-when-orientation-changes-on-android ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ActionBarSherlock. This is a behavior of Android and you shouldn't fight it.