# Android App Acts as if it is Launching when Rotated

Tags: android

I am having an issue with my Android app returning to the state it is in whenever it is launched whenever the screen is rotated. The app has several `ImageButton`s that change their image whenever clicked on, and I have music playing in the background on a loop. Whenever the screen is rotated though, the `ImageButton`s return to their default image even if they have been changed by the user touching them, and another instance of the music loop starts to play. How can I stop this from happening? I have no idea what to do about the `ImageButton`s. As for the music loop, I have tried using `onStart()`, but it continues to happen anyway, even if I use a `boolean` to check if it has already completed the tasks once.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if(firstRun)
    {
        super.onStart();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        firstRun = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [android handle orientation change](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+handle+orientation+change)

Comment: Read this article. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: It doesn't **act like**. It **is** actually restarted. It's the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic behavior of android activities . Actually your app is not restarting but the Activity is restarting. You can use the solutions mentioned at :

[How to avoid restarting activity when orientation changes on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568558/how-to-avoid-restarting-activity-when-orientation-changes-on-android)

I would also suggest you to get a solid grasp of the Activity LifeCyle to make sure u get in less trouble due to the quirky behaviour of Android Activities/Fragments.

Also, since you want to play music in the backround, try using a Service with a persistent notification in the task bar to make sure your app is not closed abruptly by Android.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your activity declaration in the `Manifest.xml` file

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

like this:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation" />
```

Comment: Okay, now does this setting deactivate the keyboard? It's not a problem for this app, but will be if I make an app that needs it?