# Activity relaunch when change from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I build two XML-files for my activity. One in the layout Folder and the other in the layout-land folder. But when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape mode the activity relaunches. And thats exactly what i not want.
Because I'm plotting in three Graphs realtime data and the plotting should continue when I turn the Screen and not being interrupted or start new in any way.

Here is the first XML file in the layout-land Folder:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

 >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="496dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/my_layout" >

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/sensor1_graph_Feuchtigkeit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sensor1_graph_Druck"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/sensor1_graph_Temperatur"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sensor1_graph_Feuchtigkeit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensor1_graph_Feuchtigkeit"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/sensor1_graph_Druck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensor1_graph_Temperatur"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensor1_graph_Druck"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

And here the second one in layout Folder:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

 >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="496dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/my_layout" >

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/sensor1_graph_Feuchtigkeit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sensor1_graph_Druck"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/sensor1_graph_Temperatur"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sensor1_graph_Feuchtigkeit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensor1_graph_Feuchtigkeit"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/sensor1_graph_Druck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensor1_graph_Temperatur"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensor1_graph_Druck"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

In the Manifest XML it Looks like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.TomKun.testgraph.DruckActivity"
        android:label="@string/Sensor_1"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
           android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
```

If i have Manifest like this with

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
        </activity>
```

Then the layout does not change when I switch from Portrait to landscape mode. BUT the activity does not relaunch. Thats the one good thing

But if I do NOT use

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
        </activity>
```

the layout changes as i want but the activity is then relaunching.

So something in my implementation doesn't match.

Can anyone help me to solve this Problem?

I have seen that many people have similar Problems here on stackoverflow. But with these answers I couldn't solve my problem

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Well, that's how Android works. Orientation change enabled, Activity restarted. Orientation change disabled, Activity not restarted.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein But, We can see any video without loading it again in Portrait and Landscape view respectively. How ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13774855/2649012

Comment: You can use the onConfigurationChanged() METHOD TO to reload the data when orientation is changed.