# RecyclerView empty on rotate

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-orientation, recyclerview-layout

I learned from here how to prevent restart on orientation change
[How to avoid restarting activity when orientation changes on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568558/how-to-avoid-restarting-activity-when-orientation-changes-on-android)

Thus I implemented it

In my Manifest I make sure rotate doesn't trigger restart

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

My layout is very simple

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scroll">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/list_of_items"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my MainActivity I set

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView itemsView = findViewById(R.id.list_of_items);
    itemsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    itemsView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    ItemsAdapter items = new ItemsAdapter(this);
    itemsView.setAdapter(items);
}
```

Whenever rotate happens I checked inside `onConfigurationChanged` the item Count and visibility state, and log prints that the recycler view is visible and that it contains x items, yet somehow on rotate it never shows those items. What am I missing? My ItemsAdapter is a really simple adapter with nothing fancy inside.

Comment: By using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in your `onConfigurationChanged()` you basically create new view every time the device is rotated. But you only set the adapter once, for the view which you've found in your `onCreate()`. Deleting this line from `onConfigurationChanged()` should fix your problem. 

And by the way, most likely you need ScrollView, RecyclerView handles it's own scrolling.

Comment: @JanStoltman I will accept it as correct answer if you post it as one. It worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in your `onConfigurationChanged()` you basically create new view every time the device is rotated. But you only set the adapter once, for the view which you've found in your `onCreate()`. Deleting this line from `onConfigurationChanged()` should fix your problem.

And by the way, most likely you need ScrollView, RecyclerView handles it's own scrolling.