# Proper handle of variable/function according to lifecycle in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I want to change variable value or call function according to lifecycle in jetpack compose. I tried according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71603407/11560810). Also read from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect). I did this without any problem.

I have `@Composable` function

```
@Composable
fun BluetoothConnectionContentStateful(
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
    viewModel: PairViewModel = getViewModel()
) {
    var selectedIndexOfAvailableItem by remember { mutableStateOf(DEVICE_NOT_SELECTED_INDEX) }
    val rememberPairScreenState = rememberConnectionScreenState(context, viewModel)
    val bluetoothEnableState by remember { derivedStateOf { viewModel.isBluetoothEnabled } }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = bluetoothEnableState) {
        viewModel.handleBluetoothScanState(rememberPairScreenState.bluetoothAdapter)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = selectedIndexOfAvailableItem) {
        viewModel.handleTimeWarning(selectedIndexOfAvailableItem)
    }

    ComposableLifecycle { source, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) {
             viewmodel.stopScan()
        } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
          viewModel.handleBluetoothScanState(rememberPairScreenState.bluetoothAdapter)
        }
    }
}
```

**ComposableLifecycle**

```
@Composable
fun ComposableLifecycle(
    lifeCycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
    onEvent: (LifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit
) {
    DisposableEffect(lifeCycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
            onEvent(source, event)
        }
        lifeCycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifeCycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

**PairViewModel**

```
class PairViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    companion object {
        private const val WARNING_PERIOD_IN_MILLES: Long = 60000 // For 1 minute scan
        const val DEVICE_NOT_SELECTED_INDEX = -1
    }

    var isBluetoothEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    private var job = Job()
        get() {
            if (field.isCancelled) field = Job()
            return field
        }

    fun startScan(adapter: BluetoothAdapter) = viewModelScope.launch {
        // start scan
    }

    fun stopScan(adapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
       // stop scan
    }


    fun handleBluetoothScanState(bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
        if (isBluetoothEnabled) {
            startScan(bluetoothAdapter)
        } else {
            cancelTimeWarning()
            stopScan(bluetoothAdapter)
        }
    }


    fun handleTimeWarning(selectedIndexOfAvailableItem: Int) {
        if (selectedIndexOfAvailableItem == DEVICE_NOT_SELECTED_INDEX) {
            startTimeWarning()
        } else {
            cancelTimeWarning()
        }
    }

    fun startTimeWarning() {
        viewModelScope.launch(job) {
            delay(WARNING_PERIOD_IN_MILLES)
            // make event here
        }
    }

    internal fun cancelTimeWarning() {
        if (job.isActive) {
            job.cancel()
        }
        // make event here
    }
}
```

**Note** `bluetoothEnableState` is Bluetooth **ON** and **OFF** i.e. **true** and **false** respectively.

I am listening `bluetoothEnableState` using `LaunchedEffect` when **bluetooth** state change **ON** or **OFF**. This is working fine. Now the problem occur,

**1.** when activity start the `viewModel.handleBluetoothScanState(rememberPairScreenState.bluetoothAdapter)` is called two times on `onResume` and `LaunchedEffect`.

**2.** when user disable bluetooth it state change to `false` and he goes to `onPause`. After coming back `onResume` `handleBluetoothScanState` will call and also change the bluetooth state to **true** then again call the `LaunchedEffect`.

I will explain more detail of 2nd condition

```
On Resume             Close App   Open App
Bluetooth disable ->  On Pause -> OnResume -> Bluetooth enable
      |                              |            |
     \ /                            \ /          \ /
Launcheffect                      function     Launcheffect
```

So I want to prevent to call double time function so any idea how can we solve this? Thanks

Comment: Isn't that the expected outcome?, `onResume` will be called when you minimized the app and go back,  and since based on your diagram, `LaunchedEffect's` boolean `key` changes from false to true, it will also trigger.

Comment: yes but can we automise the logic?

Comment: why do you need to call `viewModel.handleBluetoothScanState` in `onResume`? when `LaunchedEffect` already reacts to bluetooth ON(`true`) and OFF(`false`) ?

Comment: I don’t have much experience with Compose yet, but my understanding is Composables are intended for creating UI, not doing all the behavior of your app. LaunchedEffects should be rarely used, but you seem to be trying to use them all over, frequently. It seems the things you are doing in the LaunchedEffects above you should be managing completely outside any Composable.

Comment: In this case you are involving the composable in telling the ViewModel that its own property has changed. Seems to me that should be handled entirely within the ViewModel instead of creating code spaghetti.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right that I am doing so much code wrong here. I used `LaunchEffect` because I am changing the code outside.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I did all business logic in view-model except this `LaunchEffect` logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your use-case and I can't compile your code, but since you only want to `startScan` when blueTooth is `ON` and `stopScan` when blueTooth is `OFF`, I think you don't need to handle the same call/logic in your `onResume`

```
// I don't think you need it here,
else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
      viewModel.handleBluetoothScanState(rememberPairScreenState.bluetoothAdapter)
}
```

since `LaunchedEffect` already reacts to bluetooth state changes ON(`true`)/OFF(`false`) and its already calling the same function in your ViewModel.

Comment: yes you are right I don't need it.