# Locking the orientation of my android phone

Tags: java, android, orientation

I'm writing an Android app. How do I lock the orientation of the phone in the portrait mode?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android

Answer (score 1):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add the following tag `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the Activity block. A sample would be:

```
    <activity android:name=".FusionDrone"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Answer (score 0):

the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` would be the way to go but if you want to do it programmatically, just call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in your `onCreate()`