# Android soft keyboard resize layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-softkeyboard

When the virtual keyboard opens, it resizes my layout. 
How can i made for put the keyboard on my layout? And what it doesn't re-size my layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` worked for me.  It's undocumented at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft but it's mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020721/android-how-to-avoid-layout-being-pushed-when-keyboard-invoked/19520735.  Also, Android Studio presented it to me as an option when I typed `android:windowSoftInputMode="`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use manifest flags to configure the effect of the virtual keyboard. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: you use which option to prevent the keyboard from affecting the layout ?

Comment: "adjustPan" - Read the API description of that and adjustResize in the link I posted.

Answer (score 5):

Android soft keyboard resize layout

```
<activity android:name=".activity.SignUpActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

It's Working for me try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<application
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
</application>
```

`adjustPan` only resizes the input field by pushing it up just a little above the keyboard, in which case the keyboard still covers every other view beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

use only this code:

```
    <application
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    </application>
```

used in manifest-application tag for all application

Comment: not working..the android:windowSoftInputMode should be on every activity like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49643125/5545574)