# Android: How to avoid layout being pushed when keyboard invoked

Tags: android, xml, layout, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync_noanim" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageButton>
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

when the softkeyboard invoked by clicking on the edit text the whole layou is being pushed. Can i keep the buttons on the header fixed and let the imageview being pushed?? Because buttons are gonna act like navigation bar so it should be there even when the layout is being pushed up.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read article here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html
You should add in manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" parameter to your activity tag.

EDITED:
Proper flag is: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" doesn't help :(

Comment: Try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`. [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode) should be helpful.

Comment: Please try: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", I've mistaken tags. This should work :)

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" is not a valid value exposed by the API - the project errors out with that.

Comment: Would be nice to edit your real answer so we don't have to look into the comments to get the right one.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii Is this still the case?  My app doesn't seem to error with it and it's working as needed.  Only tested on HTC One with 4.1.

Comment: In fact it was suggested by my IDE which is how I found it.

Answer (score 14):

Out of all properties under **android:windowSoftInputMode** in manifest the only thing that worked is

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"**

Comment: Cant believe, Its undocumented; but this solved my issue ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This solved my issue as well! Thank you, my layout was not a scrollable view so naturally it would push it upwards with the soft keyboard upon a fragment replace.

Comment: does anyone know if there are problems on older android versions, regarding 'adjustNothing' value ?

Answer (score 5):

In my AndroidManifest file, I added the the following code to the activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**HISTORY**

Actually, I tried AdjustResize and AdjustNothing but it didn't work on my end so I tried other ways. I found this answer useful and hope it solves your problem as well! :)