# How to resize layout with displaying keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I have an activity that inside of it displaying a fragment .I want when keyboard is displaying activity resize I try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in my manifest but it doesn't resize my layout.My layout is inside a scrollview also.

Comment: a screenshot of the issue might help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765534/android-soft-keyboard-resize-layout ..refer to this..

Answer (score 0):

Introduced the following property for your activity tag in the manifest file:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Also you needed to add following code in the activity's OnCreate function:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```