# input breaks my dialog activity as it makes it smaller

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I`ve been trying to prevent the keyboard to resize my activity which has dialog theme but nothing happens. I`ve tried almost everything but I cant help it. I am trying to make the keyboard to overlap the activity rather than to push it. Here is my code any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Its in RelativeLayout and thats the following code. I`ve tried to put some commands in the manifest but its not working at all. Is there a way around it??

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bought"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bought"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Confirm" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in your `activity` tag in the manifest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard resize layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765534/android-soft-keyboard-resize-layout)

Comment: @BenP. its not working mate