# Phonegap deviceready event

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have a question regarding this event here, deviceready.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    app.init();
}, false);
```

It appears the event is fired every time the device (I'm working on Android 2.3) is tilted to the side (So that the display changes to wide). I guess this is the intended behavior, but is there any way to prevent it, as my application needs to be initialized only once?

Comment: Would love to answer this in a more correct way but I need to jet,  a quick hack answer is `app.init = function(){};` right after the `app.init()` call :P

Comment: Starred will come back tomorrow!

Comment: Good guess, but it looks like the DOM gets reloaded every time. So changing javascript won't do it I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't think there is going to be a way around this, I'm pretty sure thats the intended design (think about market app it does the same thing). You probably just want to disable landscape rotation for the app? `<activity   ........      android:screenOrientation="portrait">`

Comment: Oh sorry if I sounded harsh, english is not my primary language. That second solution is a good idea, i'll look into that!

Comment: LoL. Not you, I meant the dom reloading. Sounds mental. Probably logical though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the solution

[How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

By adding

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file, it tells the app that you will handle the configChanges yourself.