# android ViewSwitcher orientation issues

Tags: android, screen-orientation, viewswitcher

I have a viewSwitcher containing two views. Is it possible that when I am on a certain view, to block screen orientation changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check here: [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android) and here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b96a845cbce44af4?pli=1 on how to set requested orientation on runtime. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't need to disable orientation changes for the activity, this means that other views from switcher will not switch the orientation. I need to disable orientation only when I am on a certain view from switcher.

Comment: Yeap, when moving to this specific view you will set orientation only to landscape for example, and before you move to the next, you will enable it again.