# How to destroy an activity which handles screen orientation change and keyboard availability change?

Tags: android, android-activity, configuration

I was working with background threads and orientation changes. i have gone through the code given here.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1512263 and some other posts too.

i'm using "android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" for handling screen orientation changes. it works fine but when i want to finish this activity it gets forced close with a runtime exception with a message "Unable to destroy activity.."
any idea to finish my activity safely?

Log output is:

```
11-23 12:47:32.025: E/AndroidRuntime(438): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.FileBrowser/com.FileBrowser.mainScreenwithtab}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.FileBrowser.ScrollableTabActivity$ChangeTabBroadcastReceiver@44df87d8
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.FileBrowser.ScrollableTabActivity$ChangeTabBroadcastReceiver@44df87d8
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:667)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ApplicationContext.unregisterReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:747)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:321)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.FileBrowser.ScrollableTabActivity.onDestroy(ScrollableTabActivity.java:120)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3456)
11-23 12:47:32.125: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you implemented onConfigurationChanged method in your activity ?

Comment: Please add the log output of the exception

Comment: Yes zoombie i have implemented onconfigurationChanged method on my activity too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really use the technique you're using. I've written two blogposts about this:

[Actvity and background threads (part 1)](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/activities-and-background-threads-part-1/)
[Actvity and background threads (part 2)](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/activities-and-background-threads-part-2/)

But since fragments were introduced, there is much easier way of handling background threads now: so called [retained](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) fragments (see an example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your post inazaruk, your blogs are really helpful. can you please upload some working sample code for any lengthy process like creating thumbnails dynamically on scrolling a view(list/grid) and updating it.

Comment: Got solution i was unregistering the BroadcastReceiver twice in opPause as well as in onDestroy.

Comment: Used onSaveInstanceState to save the state of app, and destroyed all threads on onDestroy method. Blogs given by inazaruk are really helpful thanks :)