# android: How to cancel orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to cancel auto rotation of views in my app. There are a lot of posts targeting this topic[1], all of them suggesting things like setting

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or

```
 <activity android:name=".myActivity"                  
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

which does exactly what I need, but prevents onConfigurationChanged() from firing, meaning that I am not able to track the orientation of the phone any longer.
The thing is: I need to know about the orientation at some point.

Any ideas how I could get the orientation of the phone without enabling rotation of views?

[1] [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I suggest using the [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)?
I think you will still get the notifications even if you set the orientation in your manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain the rotation use [Display#getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29).

Comment: the weird thing is (very uncool!!): this only works if you don't fix the screen orientation (e.g. with setRequestedOrientation)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this information for rotating the screen, you should implement the onConfigurationChanged yourself.

If you need this information for any other purpose, I think you should use the sensors (accelerometer or compass)

Comment: I already overwrote onConfigurationChanged, but still my views are rotated, and I don't know how to intercept this orientation change.
I need the orientation for saving the images with the right orientation (I'm writing a camera app)

Answer (score 0):

As you say *"The thing is: I need to know about the orientation at some point."*

You can check orientation any time

```
int orientation = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
    if(orientation == 0){ //horizontal

    }else if(orientation == 1){ //vertical

    }
```

Orientation detail : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#orientation

Comment: This only works without setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);