# crashes Application class

Tags: android

I sit with the problem. Here's the thing.
I am writing an application to display pdf files.

The process of rendering files, runs parallel to the main stream. For very frequent turns the screen comes a time when all the objects in my class application become null.

how do I disable screen rotation and wait for the completion of rendering the page?

I tried used

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
>   setActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

but in setting the screen SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR, the screen orientation is changed several times

Comment: Could you please post a stack trace?

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.name/com.package.name.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Error due to the fact that the variables class Application are losing their links. This occurs at a very rapid and frequent changes screen orientation.

Comment: Can I put a delay on the change of orientation of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same question, the different answers work for one activity or the entire app: [How to disable orientation change in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)