# Disable the orientation change

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable orientation change in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

I want to disable orientation change after opening the canvas in any orientation(portrait or landscape) , but I am having problem when open the canvas in the landscape mode and change the device orientation, the orientation is not disabled.

here is the code .

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this in your code...

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

get the orientation in oncreate and set that orientation for that activity

Answer (score 3):

Add a fixed orientation for your activity from manifest using this code :(put this code inside activity tag )

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

by this your activity will be displayed in portrait mode only

Comment: Thanks Shruti,         but i don't want to open canvas only in one orientation it should be open in both the mode portrait and landscape initially but after opening the canvas, the orientation changes should be disabled. the above code works correctly if i opens the canvas in portrait mode.

Comment: ok so may be u need to use `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` this line only..

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```