# Change the "P roblem loading widget" text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

i would like to know if it's possible to change the dialog of "Problem loading widget" to something like "Widget only working on Portrait Screen". Is that possible?

I know that is not the best procedure but i'm trying to support a lot of screens and the widget_info.xml is totally unflexible with the minHeight and minWidth parameters, giving errors only in the landscape mode. All my activities are intended to work in portrait with the android:screenOrientation and android:configChanges parameters in the Manifest.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android

Comment: It's a widget, not an application.