# Phonegap with barcodescanner issue with screen rotation

Tags: cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner, screen-rotation

I'm using PhoneGap 2.2.0 and the barcode plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner (version 2.0.0)

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Cordova</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kkstyle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, onDeviceReadyFailed);

    function onDeviceReady() {

    }

    function onDeviceReadyFailed() {
        alert("device not ready");
    }

    function scanIt() {

        window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
            alert("We got a barcode\n" + "Result: " + result.text + "\n"
                    + "Format: " + result.format + "\n" + "Cancelled: "
                    + result.cancelled);
            navigator.app.loadUrl("http://m.kelkoo.com/fr/search/"
                    + result.text);
            //http://m.kelkoo.com/fr/search/9782092610954
            //window.location.href = "http://www.kelkoo.fr/ss-"+ result.text +".html";
        }, function(error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        });

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <br><br><br>
        <div id="camera">
            <button class="camera-control" onclick="scanIt();">Scan</button>
            <div style="text-align: center; margin: 20px;">
                <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width: auto; height: 120px;"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch this code on my phone(Galaxy S3 under 4.1.1) in landscape mode everything is ok. When I launch this code in portrait mode then the scan bar result is never returned and there is not error message. It just come back to the index.html, if I launch a new time the scan(in landscape) it works.

So I guess that there is a bug with the phone rotation and the phonegap barcode plug in. Someone has a solution please ?

Comment: It seems that "onActivityResult" callback of barcodescanner.java is not called at the execution. I don't know why.

Comment: The solution is here in the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android