# How can i make orientation of background remain portrait eve on screen rotation

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to make the screen orientation of the background of an xml page remain in portrait even in screen rotation. I tried

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:background="@drawable/back">
```

but it doesn't work. What should i do?

Comment: declare your orientation for this activity in the manifest file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable orientation change in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in manifest file in activity tag of that specific activity you want to show in portrait mode only

```
<activity android:name="YourActivitName" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <activity
            android:name="your activity and package name like com.example.back"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```