# Handle intent on activity start but not orientation change

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

In my `onCreate` method I have a call to `handleIntent` which is responsible for handling intents. 
Inside that call (among other things) I create fragment.

This causes that fragment to be created twice on orientation change (one which was previously created on activity start, restored from `FragmentManager`, other again created in `handleIntent` method that is called because `onCreate` method is called when orientation changes).

What is the proper way to avoid that - that is how to avoid `handleIntent` being called on orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Now, the `onConfigurationChanged` method will be called instead of `onCreate`, and you can override that to make whatever changes it is that you want.

Answer (score 0):

By default, android will re-create the activity when the orientation changes. So you are actually getting `onCreate` called when the orientation changes.

Take a look at these questions if you want more control handling orientation changes:

[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

[How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)