# How do I stop an Android app from rotating?

Tags: java, android, android-orientation, screen-rotation

I'm developing an Android application, and I don't like it to rotate when the user rotates the screen. The user will be able to use only the portrait view, but not the landscape one.

Comment: did you try to set Orientation in manifest?

Comment: The right answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637075/1034622

Answer (score 16):

Put the following in your manifest, in every activity that should not rotate:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: myApp.Animate().Rotate(360).Duration(5000).Start(); Hahahahaha. Still rotate.

Comment: You know this is 3 years old right ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this below code in your activity from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="YourPackage.name">

    //Other Activities and Intents

    <activity
        //Other lines of your activity code
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

PD: Next time searches a little in this community or in Internet, because it's a typical question and you can find a lot of answers from this and others problems, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare all the limitations/permissions in your manifest file.
Just add the following permission for your application.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, in the activity tag, use:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in manifest android:screenOrientation to your app.

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" > (...) </activity>
```