# How to restrict Android application from changin its landascape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-background, android-appbarlayout

I am in trouble with Portrait and Landscape modes of my android application. So, I want to know how to restrict my application in anyone mode only. Thanks in advance to any reply with suitable answer and problem solving solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable orientation change in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your screen Orientation in your `manifest` file, `activity` tag

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

for more detail refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Answer (score 2):

add the below code in the activity tag of your manifest file...

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: FYI, Its not `application` tag, its `activity` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:screenOrientation` to your activity tag in manifest file like below code:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.packagename.YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, but will this work with both Linear & Relative Layouts ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```