# how can i control orientation so that I can change the Activity Lifecycle(onDestroy) in android studio?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I can control orientation in eclipse but I need now change orientation in the android studio.In eclipse I find android manifest file and solved the problem from the file.But in android studio, I only find manifest.xml file.

[image: img]

[I also saw the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-do-i-disable-orientation-change-on-android)
So,how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Android Studio does not have a graphical editor for the manifest like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare screen orientation in the `Manifest.xml` file, you can set the screen's orientation in the `onCreate` method in your `Activity` which is called when your program runs.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

You can use other orientations as well. This will keep the orientation the same throughout the program's lifecycle.

If however, you want it to return to another setting after `OnDestroy` is called, simply save the orientation setting using sharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and then write an if else statement to change the value after the event.

Answer (score 0):

To control orientation ,you have to override the attribute android:configChanges  of activity in manifest.
like

```
`<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">`
```

for more detail go through this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html