# How to fit the application for both config like portrait,landscape in android?

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I have done my application in portrait configuration. When I load my application in device its coming portraint configuration. But in landscape mode i keep missing some controls. How can I  fix the screen for both configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to define different layouts for landscape and portrait. You could force android to choose the proper layout depending on orientation. You could put landscape layout xml files in “res\layout-land” and portrait in “res\layout”. 
Of course it’s always good idea to use RelativeLayout, but it depends on your application.
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/android-how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change)

If you are a beginner, you might find the following useful(read up): 
[Developing orientation aware Android apps](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/1954)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Google has released a tutorial about this recently: https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html