# how to add scrollview to screen in android?

Tags: android

I have done my application in portrait configaration but when load my application in to device its coming portraint configaration but I keep in landscape mode missing some controls. 
So I want to add scroll view to screen when changing the config to landscape. How I can add ScrollView to screen ?

Comment: This is very similar to (if not the same as) your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012332/how-to-fit-the-application-for-both-config-like-portrait-landscape-in-android  If you didn't like the answers you got there please update your previous question rather than asking it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define two version of your layout.
"res/layout/your_layout.xml" - this will be used in portrait mode
"res/layout-land/your_layout.xml" - android will use this when in landscape orientation

If you don't want to do to many changes in your layout you can add ScrollView to landscape version of your_layout.xml.

Regards!