# Using an application in Landscape mode also?

Tags: java, android

I've an application running successfully, the application runs only in portrait mode only, if i'm going to change this to landscape, it's also possible to change. But, it won't never come to portrait mode. How can i use these (portrait & landscape) in same time? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just looked at related links at bottom right side of your question and [found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2012332/593709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code where you have to change portrait to landscape,

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

use this to change landscape to portrait.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I can't change my result in simultaneously, it's working only at once.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the app to run in land and port you don't need to place anything just take out the code line that is forcing it. Hope it helps