# Android Ignore Flip

Tags: android, orientation

I would like to have my android app ignore flip, is that possible? I added android:screenOrientation="portrait" to all of my activities but that is about as effective as the close door button on an elevator.

Comment: Does your app ignore flip when you do that? Does it behave in any odd way? As far as I've experienced if you want to overwrite the default behavior of all apps (to be able to flip) then you have to explicitly state what orientation each of your activities is running in. Since this is what you are doing I would like to know if it works for you.

Comment: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` works just fine, for its stated purpose.

Comment: Maybe my question is bad. Actually the view stays the same but it reloads my activity for some reason. Should it do that?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your answer can be found here: [android-how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/android-how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change)